# ORA-00936: missing expression Error

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle11g

I searched for answers before posting this question because I know someone must have had similar error in the past. But unfortunately I still dont get the answer.
I just need to insert a small data from access 2003 into Oracle 11g. 
Since access and oracle datasources have been mapped in my local machine, I do the following to move data from access to Oracle:
(The tables and columns on both access and Oracle are the same, because the one in access was imported from an excel, the values were manipulated manually and now need to be inserted 
into Oracle).

```
<cfquery name = "X" datasource="myaccess_local"> <!--- In access --->
 select * from ad_reportdetail
</cfquery>

    <cfset v_count=1>
<cfloop query="X">  
   <!--- In Oracle --->
   <cfquery name = "Y" datasource="MyOrc_Prod">
    INSERT INTO AD_REPORTDETAIL (FId,
                                 CID,
                                 FName,
                                 TLog,
                                 LogNotes,
                                 ThisProf,
                                 F_Proc,
                                 CProg,
                                 Status)
    VALUES (#FId#,
            #CId#,
            '#Trim(FName)#',
            '#Trim(TLog)#',
            '#Trim(LogNotes)#',
            '#Trim(ThisProf)#',
            '#Trim(F_Proc)#',
            '#Trim(CProg)#',
            '#Trim(Status)#')
   </cfquery>

 <cfset v_count= v_count + 1>  
</cfloop>
```

When I ran the above template, I got:

The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
Error Executing Database Query.

[Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-00936: missing expression

The error occurred in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\sc\DEV\MyTEST\myapp.cfm: line 30
28 :                '#Trim(F_Proc)#',
29 :                '#Trim(CProg)#',
30 :                '#Trim(Status)#')
31 :       
32 :

The problem is, 1 row got inserted before it threw this error at me
I can't find any syntax error, if there is syntax error how come the first row got inserted?
Please help!

Comment: Do any of the values like Fname, notes log etc... contain special characters such as pipe | or tic ' or double quotes that could be throwing off the query?  If so, I would suggest using prepared statements instead.  your current approach allows for SQL injection  and doens't handle special characters well.

Comment: Paramaterized queries not prepared statements. http://www.phillipciske.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/4/12/Basic-Web-Application-Security--SQL-Injection as an example